# How to create a custom calabash step to run a command?

Tags: android, cucumber, calabash, calabash-android

I am using [calabash-android](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android) to test my app. I want to create a custom step which executes an `adb` command.

**This is what I tried:**

I created the following custom step which takes no arguments (I created it under step_definitions/ folder):

```
Run adb command for our app do |cukes|
   system("adb devices")
end
```

In `my_first.feature`, I call above step like this:

```
Feature: My feature

  Scenario: My scenario
    Run adb command for our app
```

When I run the test with the command `calabash-android run myApp.apk`, I get an error message:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
Run adb command for our app do |cukes|
```

Where am I wrong? How to create a simple step which takes no argument & just runs one adb command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues:

- `Run` isn't a Gherkin identifier. Start your step with `Given`, `When`, `Then`, `And` or `But`.
- Step definitions don't have the bare wording of the step, but a regular expression that matches it.
- The number of block parameters should match the number of capture groups in the regular expression. In this case there aren't any, so there should be no block parameters.

This should work:

features/my_first.feature

```
Feature: My feature

  Scenario: My scenario
    When I run the adb command for our app
```

step_definitions/my_first_steps.rb

```
When /^I run the adb command for our app$/ do
  system("adb devices")
end
```